# error while trying to connect to Oracle database 11g using groovy scripting in soapui

Tags: groovy, soapui

```
import java.sql.Connection
import groovy.sql.Sql
connectionString = "jdbc:oracle:thin:/user/pwd@mshist"
def driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver";

sql = Sql.newInstance(connectionString, driverClassName);
def row = sql.execute("select * from PROCESS_ORDER" );
//java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver:error at line :7
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a JDBC (Java DataBase Connector) for your achitecture. Just Google "Oracle JDBC", or you can ask one of your developers to give it to you - they will most definitely have it. Place it in SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext and try again.

Once you get past that, depending on which version of SoapUI you are using, you may need to [register the JDBC](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/tips-a-tricks.html#10-use-a-jdbc-driver-from-inside-a-groovy-script):

```
com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver( "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" )
```